# How can I create Nginx IIS LoadBalancer by using Powershell over Octopus?

Tags: powershell, nginx, devops, octopus-deploy, octopus

How can I create Nginx load balancer with IIS? This question is not easy to describe for me. So I separated 2 phases about my problem.

1)there is  1 Nginx server(app.xyz.com) infront of IIS Websites (app1.xyz.com,app2.xyz.com,app3.xyz.com ) All requests are sent to app.xyz.com because it is a load balancer. Is it easy to do that?  How can I do that by using Octopus with powershell.

2) I have to stop app1.xyz.com by deploying while app2.xyz.com and app3.xyz.co. working.

When

```
 app1.xyz.com (DOWN)    app1.xyz.com (UP)     app1.xyz.com (UP)
 app1.xyz.com (UP)      app1.xyz.com (DOWN)   app1.xyz.com (UP)
 app1.xyz.com (UP)      app1.xyz.com (UP)     app1.xyz.com (DOWN)
```

step by step deploying without stopping all web apps. Please look at below pictures What I draw:

[image]

[image]

**nginx.conf:**

```py
worker_processes  4;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;


 upstream loadbalancer.xyz.com {
    server staging1.xyz.com:996;
    server staging2.xyz.com:997;
    keepalive 15;
  }

server {
    listen 999;

    location / {


      proxy_pass https://loadbalancer.xyz.com;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  If you show some existing research/effort, you're more likely to get help.

Comment: @boxdog I uploaded my nginxfile. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't completely sold on using nginx for the load balancer i've done the same thing you are describing with using IIS as a proxy / load balancer which routes to the application IIS servers behind it. You can then use windows network load balancer to make your proxy / load balancers for your proxies (assuming you make more than 1) for high availability too if you desire. If that is something you are interested in I can help you out with that but using nginx i'm not the best with for load balancers. I'd comment but i'm new to stack overflow... Sorry...